# move_uploaded_file not working on Apache server in Linux Mint

Tags: php, apache, upload, linux-mint

So I am trying to do a basic upload via an HTML form and a simple php script, but the move_uploaded_file function always returns false. I have run "chmod 777" on the directory (I will deal with safety more when I actually get this to work) and the "upload" directory is in the htdocs folder (actually /var/www in Ubuntu Server and Linux Mint).

Here is the form:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

...and upload_file.php...

```
<?php
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0){
        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }else{
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"/var/www/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){ 
                echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }else{
                echo "Failed to move uploaded file";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
    }
?>
```

When I try to upload a small JPEG, I get "Failed to move file". Any thoughts?

Comment: Do **NOT** use the `['name']` parameter to store the file, unless you've take large amounts of security precautions. That name value is FULLY under the remote user's control, and using it blindly as you are lets that user scribble on ANY file on your server. e.g. they can hack the upload and name their file `../../../../../etc/passwd`.

Comment: Enable full error reporting and log error messages into a file. You should see the details so you'll reduce the amount of guessing required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script needs to be able to write to the destination directory, which in this case would be /var/www/upload/ (is that the directory where you changed the permissions?). Also you are using the client's local name which could be a possible problem and security issue (not necessarily the reason here though).

Comment: Wow... I changed the permissions for /var/www/, and thought I had done so recursively... Nope. Changed permissions for /var/www/upload specifically and now it works... Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When i found out that my OS was the problem i wanted to destroy my pc.

```
chmod ugo+rwx yourfoldername
```

With this way you give permission to everyone to write/read/delete to your folder.